# Is map<string1, map<string2, map<string3, string> > > slower than concatenating the strings to map<string1string2string3, string>?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I need to access some data according to three different criteria, like this:

```
my_map["string1"]["string2"]["string3"]
```

Now I wonder if it makes sense to concatenate the strings in this way:

```
my_map["string1|string2|string2"]
```

Would this save time for lookup operations?
Are there other important factors to consider?

Comment: Why don't you test it out?

Comment: Yes first one will be slower

Comment: Is it worth it? Which one is easiest to use?

Comment: You probably don't want to concatenate and copy strings all the time, consider using `std::map<std::tuple<std::string,std::string,std::string>,X> my_map;` where lookup can be done efficiently with `my_map[std::tie("string1","string2","string3")]`.

Comment: Are your strings guaranteed to not have `|` in them? You can also do `map<SomeStructOrClass, string>`, where `SomeStructOrClass` is a struct or class holding your three strings. (Combining them, and providing < for them.) (Edit: Daniel's suggestion is essentially this; std::tuple is a convenient way of doing this.)

Comment: Have you considered creating a `Key` type that holds the three strings and provides the appropriate `operator<` (or a comparison function)?

Comment: @Thanatos The really important thing is to use `std::tie` for the lookup to avoid copying the strings.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Whether you use `tie` or not, a copy of the strings for the key will be done. `make_tuple` seems to make this copy more obvious in real code.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Storing it, yes, but it makes the lookup more efficient! (Edit: At least in C++14's `find()`, not with C++11 or `[]`)

Comment: @DanielFrey: I checked C++11 and `find` takes exactly the same value as is stored in the key. That was the reason for the comment.

Comment: Do you need them in a particular order?  Because if not, `unordered_map` will be much, much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question should be preceded by looking at the use-cases you need to support. If your data is hierarchical and you need to access whole sub-parts of it (like passing `my_map["criteria1"]`, you should stick with the first version.

If that is not the case and you only have one large set of data with three orthogonal criteria, you could optimize the access. Concatenating the strings is not the best approach as it creates certain overhead for copying and concatenating strings and you need to be careful about the separator, probably even requiring you to escape certain characters which introduces more overhead and more complexity, which mean: More bugs. Instead, you want to store the three criteria in a single, suitable key type: `std::tuple`.

Your map could look like (given is stores values of some type `X`):

```
using my_key_type = std::tuple<std::string,std::string,std::string>;
std::map< my_key_type, X > my_map;
```

Adding values works like this:

```
my_map.emplace( my_key_type( "A", "B", "C" ), x ); // x is a value of type X
```

And lookup can be done efficiently with:

```
X x = my_map[ std::tie( "A", "B", "C" ) ];
```

As pointed out by David Rodríguez, `std::tie` doesn't buy much efficiency when used with `[]`, but it is shorter than `std::make_shared`. Anyways, you will have a benefit in the future with C++14 when you use `my_map.find( std::tie( "A", "B", "C" ) );` which will allow the compiler to omit copying the strings for lookup.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably not a good idea to do that for two main reasons:

- it makes things more inscrutable and complex for those who come behind you
- in-band signalling opens you up to all sorts of fun security exploits when someone puts a separator character in one of the strings

You should probably look for data structures that do what you want with proper design, like [tuples](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/).